# Formatting results in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to get my results to look like the following in a JFrame:

```
Cylinder 1
Radius = 5
Height = 5
Volume = 392.7

Cylinder 2
Radius = 5
Height = 5
Volume = 392.7

Cylinder 3
Radius = 5
Height = 5
Volume = 392.7
```

Instead I get:

```
Cylinder 1 Radius = 5 Height = 5
Volume = 392.7  Cylinder 2
Radius = 5  Height = 5
Volume = 392.7 Cylinder 3
Radius = 5 Height = 5
Volume = 392.7
```

I have tried re-sizing the frame, \n, etc with no luck. If I make it bigger, it just makes the line of data longer.  I cannot make it small enough to have the results on each line. My code is below, can anyone show me what the heck I am missing.  Thanks!!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Output JFrame variables
                JLabel labelCylinder[] = new JLabel[3];
                JLabel labelRadius[] = new JLabel[3];
                JLabel labelHeight[] = new JLabel[3];
                JLabel labelVolume[] = new JLabel[3];
                JFrame outputFrame = new JFrame("Results");
                outputFrame.setBounds(150, 150, 325, 150);
                outputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                outputFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                // For loop to output results
                for (int o=0; o<myCylinder.length;o++)
                {
                    myCylinder[o] = new Cylinder(Double.parseDouble(textRadius[o].getText()), Double.parseDouble(textHeight[o].getText()));


                    labelCylinder[o] = new JLabel();
                    labelCylinder[o].setText(" Cylinder " + (o+1) + "\n");
                    labelRadius[o] = new JLabel();
                    labelRadius[o].setText("\nRadius = " + myCylinder[o].getRadius() + "\n");
                    labelHeight[o] = new JLabel();
                    labelHeight[o].setText("\nHeight = " + myCylinder[o].getHeight() + "\n");
                    labelVolume[o] = new JLabel();
                    labelVolume[o].setText("\nVolume = " + myCylinder[o].volume() + "\n");

                    outputFrame.add(labelCylinder[o]);
                    outputFrame.add(labelRadius[o]);
                    outputFrame.add(labelHeight[o]);
                    outputFrame.add(labelVolume[o]);


                }
```

Comment: use `BoxLayout` instead of `FlowLayout`

Comment: Use non editable JTextArea

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - that data seems to the type that would best be presented in tabular form (using a `JTable`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `outputFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout())` to (single column) [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) for this.  See [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) & [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: And if you want to just use one JLabel, then JLabel supports html tags.

You can use in one label itself 
`label1.setText('<html>Radius: somevalue <br/> Height : someHeight <br/>...<html>');`

Comment: Have been working with a box layout and now get:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.AWTError:       BoxLayout can't be shared.

Have read the links you sent, have been on them alreadt tryng to figure out my problem.

Comment: If you can share full runnable class with main, I can try to change it.